# How to set CPU fan speed permanently in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, linux-mint, fan, thinkpad

I followed [this](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed) tutorial to adjust the CPU fan speed on my old ThinkPad R60, which used to get uncomfortably warm at high CPU loads (up to 70 °C) and the fan was not revving up properly. How can the setting be made *permanent*, so I don't have to execute

```
# echo level 7 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

and enter administrator credentials every time the system is rebooted? I'm running LMDE 4.

Comment: Just a side note, 70 C is a normal operating temperature for a CPU under load.

Comment: At higher loads, both the exhaust air and the *left* handrest gets really warm (wrist starts to hurt), which is strange, since there seems to be no hot component underneath (mainly the empty ExpressCard bay). I already replaced the old thermal paste, but the only thing that seems to help is higher fan RPM - the factory settings appear way to low. The classic ThinkPads have an magnesium endoskeleton, I suspect that it's conducting heat from somewhere to the handrest. I cannot exclude the possibility that it's not the CPU, but maybe some other component(s) - maybe the RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start at the BIOS level which should be F1 when you're booting up for a ThinkPad R60. Check under UEFI settings, if not there, try poking around for the settings under CPU-related stuff. I'm not familiar with that specific BIOS and how it's organized.

**Update:**

If you do not have a BIOS related setting, there are instructions at the following link on how to configure the fan speeds using thinkfan:

[askubuntu.com/a/1139409/340979](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139409/340979)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I will check if there is a BIOS option for this, but if I remember correctly, there isn't

Comment: If not, I just ran into this https://askubuntu.com/a/1139409/340979

Comment: And hey, it let me comment on my own answer at least..

Comment: Ah, that solves the question - the tutorial you linked specifies how to set and configure the automatic startup of `ThinkFan`. Thx!

Comment: @StephenSabatini Since that comment you made helped the OP solve his question, you should edit your answer to include that information. Thanks for the contribution, and welcome to Super User!

Comment: Done. Thank you, @SamForbis.

Comment: Glad it helped @david